# Run arguments in Screen - Ecplise

Tags: eclipse, arguments

I've searched but I found nothing about it.

Is there an easy way to set the run arguments (a windows like the console, error log...)?

I'm asking this because I need to change several arguments and I don't want to go to `Config-> Arguments-> Run`

Answer (score 0):

```
Run -> Run Configurations
```

From there select the `Arguments` tab and pass in you arguments. This config can be saved for future use.

[image]

You can't add this as a view in your perspective, but you could create a shortcut for it by going to:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys
```

Comment: I know this. What I'm asking for is a window in my workspace that allows me to change that without having to go there.

Comment: in that case, no.  you could always create a custom shortcut to it if you want to speed up the process. see edit